# Call save() in model while using Propel Versionable

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I just switched an existing Model to be `Versionable`.

After debugging quite a lot, I now realized that there are a quite a few cases that I use `$this->save()` in the model quite a few times and that this finally causing duplicate entries in the Version table.

Is the only way to prevent this by removing the `-save()` methods out of the model (I tried it out, it works) or is there another, more simple way to prevent the internal loop during version-creation and its saving?

Comment: You could create your own custom behavior to only trigger the versioning saves when you want to.

Comment: Hi nobleuplift. 

Thats what i thought of as well but how would i do that? I'd have to see whether 'save' has been called from the model (no versioning) or from the controller (versioning). How couls i do that? Is there a way to get the current call stack in symfony? Thanks! Steffen

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify a version of Propel, I'm assuming the stable version 1.x, though the following might well apply to 2.x, which is in alpha5 at the time of writing.

As per [this documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/behaviors/versionable), you can specify when it is appropriate to save a new version of model rows using this method:

```
class Book extends BaseBook
{
  public function isVersioningNecessary($con = null)
  {
    return $this->getISBN() !== null && parent::isVersioningNecessary($con);
  }
}
```

If that method returns false, the last version is overwritten; if it is true, a new version is created.

(The docs are slightly wrong in that I assume the parent should take a `$con` parameter: missing there, fixed here).